# Error during installation of Robot Framework and RIDE

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I need to install Python 3.8.10 , Robot Framework 3.1.2, RIDE v2.0b1.

Getting an error (below). Could anyone help me with the installation?

```
20220906 10:39:43.191 [ERROR]: Error in listener: C++ assertion "CheckExpectedParentIs(w, m_containingWindow)" failed at ..\..\src\common\sizer.cpp(887) in wxSizer::SetContainingWindow(): Windows managed by the sizer associated with the given window must have this window as parent, otherwise they will not be repositioned correctly.

Please use the window wxMiniFrame@000001D95A145300 ("frame", HWND=000000000001077C) with which this sizer is associated, as the parent when creating the window wxHtmlWindow@000001D95A0A74E0 ("htmlWindow", HWND=000000000001077E) managed by it.
While handling <robotide.publish.messages.RideTreeSelection object at 0x000001D95DE7CB80>

Traceback (most recent call last):
C++ assertion "CheckExpectedParentIs(w, m_containingWindow)" failed at ..\..\src\common\sizer.cpp(887) in wxSizer::SetContainingWindow(): Windows managed by the sizer associated with the given window must have this window as parent, otherwise they will not be repositioned correctly.

Please use the window wxMiniFrame@000001D95A145300 ("frame", HWND=000000000001077C) with which this sizer is associated, as the parent when creating the window wxHtmlWindow@000001D95A0A74E0 ("htmlWindow", HWND=000000000001077E) managed by it.
```

Comment: What exactly are you running when this error occurs? What have you done previously to set up your environment?

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from a C++ library in wxWidgets that wxPython uses.
It would be nice to know what version of wxPython you have installed. However, the version of RIDE, v2.0b1 is somewhat old, and you can now try the newest, v2.0b2, by using the command:

```
pip install -U --pre robotframework-ride
```

For more information, see RIDE project page, [here](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE).